# Access the new state of an edited array

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects within a users profile that I'm trying to update with a form. I'm having trouble figuring out how to update the array. When I load the current example it renders fine, it allows me to update the `<input>` fields, however, when I submit the form and try to access the updated experiences array the array hasn't updated.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Parent**

```
class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    const { experiences } = this.props;

    console.log(experiences);
  }

  render() {
    const { id, experiences } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div className="form-row mb-2">
            <div className="col">
              <ul className="list-unstyled">
                {experiences.map((position, index) => (
                  <Position
                    key={`position-${id}-${index}`}
                    id={id}
                    index={index}
                    title={position.title}
                  />
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            Update
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
class Position extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      index: props.index,
      title: props.title
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const { target } = event;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const { name } = target;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    const { index, title } = this.state;

    return (
      <li>
        <div>
          <input
            name="title"
            placeholder="Position title"
            type="text"
            value={title || ''}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            className="form-control mb-2"
            id={`title-${id}-${index}`}
            aria-describedby="title"
          />
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only updating the local state of the child component and nothing in the `experiences` array in the parent component. The common pattern here is to pass a callback to the child component to update the "source of truth" in the parent, the form input values in this case.

**Profile**

```
class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      experiences: props.experiences, // store form input values in form
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event, index) {
    const { target } = event;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;

    // copy old state and update the value matching the index
    this.setState(prevState => prevState.experiences.map((experience, i) => {
      return index === i ? value : experience;
    });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    const { experiences } = this.state;

    console.log(experiences);
  }

  render() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    const { experiences } = this.state; // experiences from state

    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div className="form-row mb-2">
            <div className="col">
              <ul className="list-unstyled">
                {experiences.map((position, index) => (
                  <Position
                    key={`position-${id}-${index}`}
                    id={id}
                    index={index}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    title={position.title}
                  />
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            Update
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Position**

```
class Position extends Component {
  render() {
    const { handleInputChange, id, index, title } = this.props;

    return (
      <li>
        <div>
          <input
            name="title"
            placeholder="Position title"
            type="text"
            value={title || ''}
            onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, index)}
            className="form-control mb-2"
            id={`title-${id}-${index}`}
            aria-describedby="title"
          />
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```